# MySQL Select From Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, search

Im creating a database and it has the following tables & Following columns:

- Student - (studentId,studentName,degree)
- Module - (moduleId,moduleName,credit)
- Registered - (studentId,moduleId)
- Staff - (staffId,staffName,grade)
- teaches - (staffId,moduleName)

What i want from the search is to search for modules which are taught by a certain tutor.

So for example if James Wilkinson is teaching english and maths it would show as a result the module he teaches with the module id.

Comment: Simple joins are required, please post where you got stucked before we help you.

Comment: All i had was a search with all of the tables specified and which columns and finally a where case. But it brought up loads of results. But the join was missing

Comment: Im now trying to view students who are taught by certain tutors. I havent got a clue on how i can get this to work.

SELECT student.studentId,student.studentName FROM student INNER JOIN teaches ON teaches.moduleId = module.moduleId INNER JOIN staff ON staff.staffId = teaches.staffId WHERE staff.staffName = 'alan turing';

Comment: I think ive done it, but could some one verify its correct?

SELECT student.studentId,student.studentName
FROM student
INNER JOIN registered
ON student.studentId = registered.studentID
INNER JOIN teaches
ON registered.moduleId = teaches.ModuleID
INNER JOIN staff
ON staff.staffId = teaches.staffIdWHERE staff.staffName = 'alan turing';

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select Module.Moduleid from Module inner join Teaches on Teaches.ModuleName=Module.ModuleName inner join staff on Staff.staffid=teaches.staffid where staff.staffname='James Wilkinso'
```

Anyway teres something wrong with your structure. Table teaches should have a moduleID field, not ModuleName.

Hope this help

Comment: is there a way to achieve this by not having the join?

Comment: Not there i know. Why? of course you could do a small program to do the same, but i see no reason for do that.

Comment: its getting used in a java application. Is this the simples way of achieving this?

Comment: well you could do your own loop and search manualy the database, but join is the easy way!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple join to me.

```
SELECT staffName, moduleName
FROM Staff a
JOIN teaches b on a.staffId=b.staffId
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select module.module_id , module.module_name, teaches.staff_id from module 
INNER JOIN on module.module_name = teaches.module_name 
where teaches.staff_id in 
(select staff_id from staff where staff.staffname='James Wilkinson')
```